# How to check if APK installed in X86 devices of Android will have x86 specific .so or arm specific .so at runtime

Tags: android, performance, assembly, android-ndk, android-x86

I have android application which used native code, we will compile and generate .so library based on X86 or arm processor based devices.

My question is once APK is installed in X86 Android device and running, how to check if .so library bundle with APK, is x86 based or arm based ??

**Example**
Lets say User has APK + native code compiled for arm processor. now User installed this APK in android X86 devices. So My Question is how to find that app is using arm based native code while it is running in that X86 device ?

[ As I know in X86 based processor support both arm as well x86 based libraries  so for those devices it is very hard to determine.]
[ for arm processor based devices, they didn't support x86 based libraries or .so so at install time it will throw error mismatch AIBS type.]

I tried "adb shell cat /proc/cpuinfo", but didn't find any thing relevant.

Please help me in this. All edits are welcome.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21480838/will-the-binaries-built-for-arm-work-on-intel-processors-android

Comment: @MorrisonChang I was trying to get the answer of "how to find out of x86 or arm binary " present inside apk running in X86 device ?

Comment: Umm, on what device did you try 'cat /proc/cpuinfo' that didn't work. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19557326/295004

Comment: @MorrisonChang it was working, but I didn't the information regarding which binary is present in the app ( i.e arm one or x86 one)

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking: if you've only packed your apk with a ARM binary and you are running on a x86 device via cpuinfo that is your answer - if you are asking to unpack an apk to see which ABI binaries are in there - that is a slightly different question.